# Swing window doesn't appear after getting input from Console

Tags: java, swing, console, jfilechooser, event-dispatch-thread

I have a simple swing window in order to load files.

This appear in the class `analyzedLoad`, in a function `analyzedloads()`

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
frame.dispose();
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
```

Where I apply the function without get an input from the user, all fine. But where I get an input from the user, in this way:

```
    int al= 0;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("for choose file, press 1; for save, press 2");
       al= in.nextInt();
       if (al== 1){
        analyzedLoad.analyzedloads(); // A static function which open the swing window
```

The window doesn't appear, and the process continue to run, without doing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: too few code, too few words, for better help soonee please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: and removing `al= in.nextInt(); if (al== 1){` makes window open again?

Comment: @Qwe: Yes, If I remove the part of getting an input from a console, Its work fine.

Comment: and if you add `System.out.println("I'm here");` as the first line in `analyzedloads()` it will be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becaue "a [scanning operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) may block waiting for input," I suspect you're blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Instead use a [*File Chooser*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to obtain a file reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a second `mywindow.setVisible(true)` after the console operation.

Comment: @It doesn't help. I add it to the class analyzedLoad, where my windows is known, and the problem continue.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to declaring the `analyzeLoad` variable as `final` and do something like so:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         analyzedLoad.analyzedloads();
    }
}
```

or since the method is static:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             YourClass.analyzedloads();
        }
    }
```

That being said, without more code we can only speculate.

Comment: It doesn't help. Can you tell me plz which more code I need to give? I wrote the relevant part in the two classes. Thanks

Comment: @AdamSh: Whenever messing around with GUI it is usually good to make a distinction between showing nothing and doing nothing. Did you try to initialize the JFrame to something that is actually visible, maybe the  `JFrame` is being opened but it is not visible. I would recommend you first create a visible `JFrame` and then try to load a `JFileChooser`

Comment: Without the input from the console, everything works fine: The window appear, and the program work well. So I guess that my GUI's defenition is fine. Also, I add fc.setVisible(true); after the define of fc, and It didn't help as well.

Comment: @AdamSh: The only thing that comes to mind is that the `Scanner` might be hanging your program. Can you try to do a `in.close()` after you get the value from `in.nextInt()`.

Comment: @AdamSh: Would it be possible to replace the console section with a radio group and a button?